# I'm using Sanity for managing the database but I'm having a problem with displaying items on my website... here is the code

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, next.js, sanity

Why items are not displayed on my website? what did I do wrong guys?
Can anyone help me or show me how to solve the issue in this block of code(index.js)

````
import { client } from '../lib/client';
import {HeroBanner,FooterBanner, Product} from '../components';
const Home = ({ products, bannerData}) => (
  <div>
    <HeroBanner heroBanner ={bannerData.length && bannerData[0]} />
    <div className="products-heading">
      <h2>Best Selling Product</h2>
      <p>Speakers of many variations</p>
    </div>
    
    <div className="products-container">
    {products?.map((product) =><Product key={product.id} product={product.name}/>)}
    </div>

    <FooterBanner footerBanner={bannerData && bannerData[0]}/>
  </div>
);

export const getServerSideProps = async () =>{
  const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
  const product = await client.fetch(query);

  const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
  const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);

  return{
    props: {product, bannerData }
  }
}

export default Home;```
````

Comment: You're passing `product` from `getServerSideProps` but accessing `products` in the `Home` component. Is the issue the typo?

Answer (score -1):

The error is that you are passing the prop `product` through your `getServerSideProps` function. You need to retrieve it correctly.

```js
const Home = ({
  products, // <---- Here you are trying to get 'products' instead of 'product'
  bannerData
}) => {  
  return (
     {/* ... */}
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  
  //...

  return {
    props: { product, bannerData } // <----- Here you are passing 'product'
  }
}
```